# URLDecode cannot decode this case property

Tags: java, urldecode, big5

Hello developers:  
I try to decode this chinese url

### %ACP%BB%DA%A4j%BE%D4

by using " java.net.URLDecoder " to decode with

### big5

but, the result is

### �P際�j戰

apparently, that is not correct.
The correct result is

### 星際大戰

can anyone tell me how to decode this url to get correct result ? 
Thanks for your help, and Happy New Year ! !

Comment: Theres 6 % signs - so decoding to 6 chars somehow makes sense. Could you show what you get on UrlEncoding for your text using big5? And maybe show the code you used?

Comment: As mentioned by @Jan the URL is wrongly encoded it should be `%AC%50%BB%DA%A4%6A%BE%D4`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer. 
1. Java take "%" as escape character with decoding string. 
2. Java process character with 2 bytes.

### So, my final solution is:

case: %ACP
step:
  1. split out 3rd character: %AC "P"
  2. transform "P" from decimal to hexadecimal value.
     "P" with decimal value: 80 to %50.
  3. recombine "%AC", "%50" to "%AC%50".
  4. URLDecoder.decode("%AC%50", "big5"), then return "星".

Comment: You can't write bandaid code for every possible encoding error. The solution here is to fix the encoding.

Comment: thx for your suggest. That solution is work for me as I held this problem.